# Meteor: installing packages from smart.json/smart.lock

Tags: meteor

I've got a project that I started on an older version of Meteor and I've now installed the most recent version.  I cloned my project code and ran into problems as soon as I ran `meteor` so I deleted all the files except the smart.json, smart.lock and packages.json

I ran `meteor add meteorhacks:npm` then `meteor` to install the node modules I require.  It looks like all the packages I need are in the smart.lock file.

This should be really simple, how do I install the most recent version of these packages?  I thought just running `meteor` would pick them up but apparently not.  I checked by by doing `meteor list` and I don't see all the packages I need.

smart.json:

```
{
  "packages": {
    "loading": {},
    "jquery-jcrop": {},
    "accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3": {},
    "accounts-ui-bootstrap-3": {},
    "font-awesome-4-less": {}
  }
}
```

smart.lock

```
{
  "meteor": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "basePackages": {
      "loading": {},
      "jquery-jcrop": {},
      "accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3": {},
      "accounts-ui-bootstrap-3": {},
      "font-awesome-4-less": {}
    },
    "packages": {
      "loading": {
    "git": "https://github.com/bitIO/meteor-loading.git",
    "tag": "v0.0.1",
    "commit": "48840a828a614e25d0e19c124494b16f255a902e"
      },
      "jquery-jcrop": {
    "git": "https://github.com/waltyuyu/meteor-jquery-jcrop.git",
    "tag": "v0.0.3",
    "commit": "45a62562f3d13cbc72a7710472a76cf9c3c589cd"
      },
      "accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3": {
    "git": "https://github.com/hharnisc/meteor-accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3.git",
    "tag": "v0.2.6",
    "commit": "fe74692303daf73d440f2729010bcf1557af62ca"
      },
      "accounts-ui-bootstrap-3": {
    "git": "https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.git",
    "tag": "v0.3.5",
    "commit": "bbd0a8a46ae02526c2ebfee05fa8075d8d04a9ba"
      },
      "font-awesome-4-less": {
    "git": "https://github.com/svub/fontawesome4-less.git",
    "tag": "v4.4.0",
    "commit": "250d2336a217c18eb70e9d074784a7db3ca38472"
      },
      "roles": {
    "git": "https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles.git",
    "tag": "v1.2.8",
    "commit": "68844ba216c348d332bdb840825850f497f515bb"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the correct meteor packages files are  `.meteor/packages` and `.meteor/versions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For meteor packages, the one you install using `meteor add package:name`

- Their version are be stored in the `.meteor/versions`
- Running `meteor update` will update them the last available version
- Typing `meteor list` will list the used packages, their version and a comment if a new version is available.

For pure NPM packages, the one you install through `meteorhacks:npm` listing them into a root based `packages.json` file

- Their version is and [must be defined](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#defining-packages) in the file directly

Example of a packages.json file:

```
{
  "redis": "0.8.2",
  "github": "0.1.8"
}
```

i.e. `"NPMModuleName":"releaseVersion"`, the alternative being to directly poing to the `aModule.tar.gz` file.

Manually finding the version can be a bit boring but just go to the project's git, and browse to the *release* path, for example: https://github.com/user/projectName/releases/

> My advise in your case, as you do not have a lot of packages to
>   reinstall, is to manually find their new name on
>   http://www.atmospherejs.com and reinstall them manually. You could
>   attempt manually editing the `.meteor/packages` file but as the
>   packages name are now (since meteor v0.9) prefixed with the contributor's name, meteor might
>   not be able to find them back. By the way, unclaimed migrated packages takes the prefix `mrt` per default For example `font-awesome-4-less` is now `mrt:font-awesome-4-less`

Comment: That's great thank you.  I was hoping there would be a quick way to run one command and have everything updated but it looks like I'll need to go through each one and add them again